# $\mathrm{Top}$ as a double category

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory, higher-category-theory

In notes of Susan Niefields about double categories (http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/26/26/26-26.pdf) one of the first examples of a double category is a double category structure on $\mathrm{Top}$, where vertical arrows are finite-intersection preserving functions between open set lattices of underlying spaces.

*---EDIT---*

I struggle to find an explanation for such construction. $\mathrm{Top}$ has more natural structures of double categories, constructed either from its monoidal structure or its bicategory. This one looks clearly not natural, so I assume it is important from some other reasons, for example encodes some properties of spaces. I clearly miss some bigger picture here, so I'll appreciate any insight.

Comment: Do you not understand what a "finite-intersection preserving function between open set lattices" is, or do you not understand how you get a double category from this?

Comment: I understand both, just this construction seems arbitrary to me, and in most cases when object seems arbitrary it turns out that I miss the deeper purpose, not that it doesn't exist

Comment: In particular, there are many double category structures on $\mathrm{Top}$, so why this particular is worth mentioning, even though looks much less natural than others?

Comment: Perhaps it is indeed arbitrary. But if that is the question you actually intended to ask, please edit your post to make it clear!

Comment: Right, sorry for causing a misunderstanding

Comment: What are the other more natural constructions you're referring to, @AlexanderGolys

Comment: For example Top has a natural structure of a bicategory, and bicategories can be made into double categories in 3 different ways. The bicategorical structure on $\mathrm{Top}$ looks way more naturally